# Delete to end of line after a match, keep lines not matched

Tags: sed, line, string-matching

I have a file of the following form:

```
interesting text-MIB blah blah blah
VERY INTERESTING TEXT
interesting text-MIB blah blah blah
```

In each line containing the "-MIB" string, I would like to delete the text following this string, until the end of the line.

The following command seems to work as intended:

```
sed -i -n -e 's/-MIB.*$/-MIB/p' ./myfile
```

My problem is that it also deletes the lines where my pattern is not found. Here, the line "VERY INTERESTING TEXT" would be deleted. I am not really familiar with sed. What am i doing wrong? Is sed appropriate for this kind of treatment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to leave out the `-n` option.
Check out http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-g_t_002d_002dquiet-7

Answer (score 10):

I have edited your `sed`. Try this,

```
sed -i.bak 's/-MIB.*$/-MIB/g' ./myfile
```

Here,

-i  - will do the changes in original file and takes the backup of original file in .bak extension

Answer (score 3):

`sed` `-n` option suppresses the default printing which is later enabled if you put `p` option after your `sed` statement.

In your example above, what you are telling `sed` is to suppress printing of all lines and then print only those lines where substitution has been done successfully. As a result the line where no substitution is made is never printed.

You need remove the `-n` option and `p` from your command:

```
sed -ie 's/-MIB.*$/-MIB/' ./myfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.