# Remove rest of each line after a certain pattern

Tags: awk

The purpose in the example is to delete the rest of the string for each line after the pattern 90000: is found

**Input file**

```
generation
122344
41572:47149-47999/2(14485-14910) 41584:47149-47999/2(14911-15449) 90000:47919-47999/2(15447-15477) 90002:47919-47999/2(15478-15418) 
41548:48094-48894/2(12844-14244) 41590:48094-48894/2(14244-14944) 41572:48094-48894/2(14945-14045) 41584:48094-48894/2(14049-14449) 90000:48094-48114/2(14447-14447) 90002:48094-48114/2(14448-14458) 
12345
```

**I tried** . This code delete only some part of the text.. The purpose is to delete all characters after finds 90000:

```
sed 's/90000:*//' file
```

**Desired output**

```
generation
122344
41572:47149-47999/2(14485-14910) 41584:47149-47999/2(14911-15449)
41548:48094-48894/2(12844-14244) 41590:48094-48894/2(14244-14944) 41572:48094-48894/2(14945-14045) 41584:48094-48894/2(14049-14449)
12345
```

Appreciate your support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete to end of line after a match, keep lines not matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297054/delete-to-end-of-line-after-a-match-keep-lines-not-matched)

Comment: @EdMorton it's missing a point before *

Comment: Corentin, exactly missing point before *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/ 9000.*/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

To fix your code try:

```
sed 's/90000:.*//'  Input_file
```

Comment: RavinderSingh13, awk '{gsub(/90000:.*/,"")} 1'  Input_file . I think is better to match exactly with the pattern, otherwise it will delete all if found " 9000"

Comment: @OXXO, I believe that is what you needed right? It is giving expected sample output as per post.